# Propagating Night Blooming Jasmine semi hardwood cuttings

Tags: cuttings

My two-semi hardwood Night Blooming Jasmine cuttings have been in a shaded corner of the sunroom for 5 weeks,when do you remove the humidity domes and move into  filtered sun?

[image]